# Give a mapping $ \nu: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow[0, \infty] $ satisfying the following properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Give a mapping $ \nu: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow[0, \infty] $ satisfying the following properties:

(a) $ \nu(\emptyset)=0 $.

(b) $ \quad \nu $ is finitely additive.

(c) $ \quad \nu $ is continuous from above.

(d) $ \quad \nu $ is not a measure.

**Attempt:** After a long search I found a suitable example:

Consider $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$, the power set $F=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$  and the mapping $\mu: F\to [0,\infty]$, $$\mu(A) := \begin{cases} 0, & \text{$A$ is a finite set} \\ \infty, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

But unfortunately I don't quite understand how it can be that a mapping is finitely additive but not sigma-additive (according to (a)). The second condition of a measure would not have to be satisfied for (d) to hold. Can someone give a detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable union
$$
\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\{k\}
$$
The measure of each singleton in the union is zero, so the (countable) sum of their measures is also zero. However, $\mu(\mathbb{N})=\infty$. The given function is not countably additive.

On the other hand, it is finitely additive because you have two options for a finite union: either $a)$ all the sets in the union are finite, hence the union itself is finite and a finite sum of zeros is zero or $b)$ one or more sets are infinite, hence the union is infinite and (finite) additivity also holds.